# command to kill/stop the program if it runs more than a certain time limit

Tags: c++, syntax, process, command, execution-time

If I have a C++ code with an infinite loop inside i want a command that will kill the execution after certain time.
so i came up with something like this-

`g++ -std=c++20 -DLOCAL_PROJECT solution.cpp -o solution.exe & solution.exe & timeout /t 0 & taskkill /im solution.exe /f`

But the problem with this was that it would first execute the program so due to the infinite loop it won't even come to timeout and taskkill part.

Does anybody have any solution to it or other alternatives instead of timeout?

I am using windows 10 and my compiler is gnu 11.2.0

Also in case there is No TLE i don't want taskkill to show this error

`ERROR: The process "solution.exe" not found.`

Comment: Why not make the loop check time since execution and let the program stop itself? Then the program is self contained and you can correctly free/release any resources the program has in use in a determintate way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main loop could exit after a certain time limit, if you're confident it is called regularly enough.

```
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using Clock = std::chrono::system_clock;

int main()
{
    auto timeLimit = Clock::now() + 1s;
    while (Clock::now() < timeLimit) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could launch a thread in your main throwing an exception after a certain delay:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
struct TimeOutException {};

int main()
{
    std::thread([]{
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); 
        std::cerr << "TLE" << std::endl;
        throw TimeOutException{};
    }).detach();

    //...
}
```

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'TimeOutException'

Comment: i am not aware about threads could you explain how this works and does this work if the infinite loop say is in a function? could it also display "TLE" if i exceed time limit?

Comment: The 2nd one would work in that case, yes, while the 1st one wouldn't.

Comment: threads are a vast topic, but essentially what is done is launching an independent task at the start of your main, which will wait for 1 sec, then display a message and throw an exception. Since this exception isn't caught anywhere, it reaches your main() and aborts the program. Unless your main thread (i.e. your regular program) ends first.